# Extract multiple Average and Moving average values over different columns in a dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe as shown below:

[image]

I would like to calculate and create new columns with the following features:

- Avg/MovingAvg over the last 1 day for quality/strength
- Avg/MovingAvg over the last 2 days for quality/strength
- Avg/MovingAvg over the last 5 days for quality/strength
- Avg/MovingAvg over the last 1 week for quality/strength
- Avg/MovingAvg over the last 2 weeks for quality/strength
- Avg/MovingAvg over the last 1 month for quality/strength

Could you please let me know how I can achieve this in pyspark.

Comment: did you try anything ? you need [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupby) for simple average, and [avg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupby) with [over](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.over) for moving average.

Comment: I am a beginner in pyspark. I have used lag to calculate the difference with previous day. But not very clear on how to calculate the average over a period of days.

Comment: I know we need a groupBy, but how to use it for getting average/moving average over a period of days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem. The answer provided by @WaqarAhmed is also another way of solving the same problem

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import *


w_1day = Window().partitionBy('device').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-1, 0)
w_2day = Window().partitionBy('device').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-2, 0)
w_5day = Window().partitionBy('device').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-5, 0)
w_7day = Window().partitionBy('device').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-7, 0)
w_14day = Window().partitionBy('device').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-14, 0)
w_21day = Window().partitionBy('device').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-21, 0)
w_30day = Window().partitionBy('device').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-30, 0)

df_avg = df.withColumn('rolling_1_day_average_q', avg("quality").over(w_1day))
df_avg = df_avg.withColumn('rolling_2_day_average_q', avg("quality").over(w_2day))
df_avg = df_avg.withColumn('rolling_5_day_average_q', avg("quality").over(w_5day))
df_avg = df_avg.withColumn('rolling_7_day_average_q', avg("quality").over(w_7day))
df_avg = df_avg.withColumn('rolling_14_day_average_q', avg("quality").over(w_14day))
df_avg = df_avg.withColumn('rolling_21_day_average_q', avg("quality").over(w_21day))
df_avg = df_avg.withColumn('rolling_30_day_average_q', avg("quality").over(w_30day))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window` in `group by` clause to specify your duration of days for the aggregation.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
```

For 1 day of aggregation with 1 day of sliding:

```
df.groupBy(f.window(col('date'), '1 day', '1 day')).agg(f.avg('strength'))
```

For 3 days of aggregation with 1 day of sliding:

```
df.groupBy(f.window(col('date'), '3 days', '1 day')).agg(f.avg('strength'))
```

Comment: w_1day = Window().partitionBy('device').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-1, 0)
df_avg = df.withColumn('rolling_1_day_average_quality', avg("quality").over(w_1day))

w_3day = Window().partitionBy('device').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-3, 0)
df_avg = df.withColumn('rolling_3_day_average_quality', avg("quality").over(w_3day))


I tried with the above lines. Do you think this is same as the one you have given?